# Sorting in Redshift table

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, amazon-redshift

I created a test table with two columns - id and name and ran following commands.

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."test1"(id integer, name character varying(256) encode lzo)distkey(id) compound sortkey(id);

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1,'First'),(2,'Second'),(4,'Fourth'),(3,'Third');

VACUUM test1
```

However on running `SELECT * FROM test1;` I am receiving following data:

[image: SELECT QUERY]

Shouldn't the returned data be sorted according to `id`? If not, how can I make sure that a SELECT query without ORDER clause returns the data sorted according to the key: `id`?

Comment: `sortkey(id)` refers to storing data in sorted order, not to your select query.

Comment: Anyway I can get sorted data using SELECT query?

Comment: There's a reason ORDER BY exists!

Answer (score 2):

You **have to use order**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ORDER_BY_clause.html):

> When a query doesn't contain an ORDER BY clause, the system returns result sets with **no predictable ordering** of the rows. The same query run twice might return the result set in a different order.

Comment: Absolutely!. this is the case in almost all databases not just Redshift. but the "random reordering" does become much more apparent of course with MPP databases.